# Liclipse won't recognize numbers in text file

Tags: python, liclipse

This is my first time using this site, so apologies if I'm asking in the wrong place.

I am working on a python assignment in liclipse. I have to import and analyze a provided text file that contains several thousand 1s and 0s and nothing else. When I look at the text file manually in the project directory outside of liclipse, it contains the correct pattern of 1s and 0s. However when I look at the text file from within Liclipse, it is completely blank. I tried to paste the data into the text file from within Liclipse, but whenever I add any numbers to the text file, they're erased instantly. This does not occur when I type any other characters into the text file from Liclipse. When I tried putting double quotes (or any other type of non-numerical character) around the 0s and 1s, liclipse only showed the non-numerical characters as if the digits didn't exist. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Seems like it's having some issue with your code... can you put it in a gist so that it can be checked?

Comment: I actually figured it out a while back then sortof forgot I posted this. It turned out to just be that the text file was WAY too long for Liclipse to properly display in its text editor. When i cut out about half the 1s and 0s from the text file, it displayed properly. Knowing this i was able to finish my assignment by using a different text editor program